# log4net logs header and footer twice

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

This is my configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net"
       type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>

  <log4net>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="Logs\StubLog.txt" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="Header" value="[Header]&#13;&#10;" />
        <param name="Footer" value="[Footer]&#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;" />
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender" >
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="Header" value="[Header]\n" />
        <param name="Footer" value="[Footer]\n\n" />
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    </root>
    <logger name="NHibernate">
      <level value="WARN" />
    </logger>
  </log4net>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

And here is the log:

```
[Header]
[Footer]

[Header]
2012-10-04 14:22:01,203 [1] INFO  Stub.Program Enter application
2012-10-04 14:22:01,328 [1] DEBUG Stub.FrmMain Test
2012-10-04 14:22:03,265 [1] INFO  Stub.Program Exit application
[Footer]
```

Where does the first pair of Header / Footer coming from? Can I eliminate them?

Comment: Don't see that issue here (Version 1.2.11.0)

Comment: I don't get the extra Header / Footer lines at the start of the log file.

Comment: Same Q:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286124/header-and-footer-coming-two-times-more-in-log4net-logs

Answer (score 4):

> Putting XmlConfigurator.Configure() at more than one places may result in having more than one header and footer pair.
>
> XmlConfigurator.Configure() should be defined only at one place in the solution. Better approach is to put it in AssemblyInfo.cs