# Header and footer coming two times more in log4net logs

Tags: c#, .net, log4net, log4net-appender

Below is the Section of log4net from app.config

```xml
   <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,     log4net" />
   </configSections>      
   <log4net debug="true">
     <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="${TMP}\SRG\Logs\Log_%env{USERNAME}_%date{yyyyMMdd}.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <bufferSize value="20" />
      <LockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <header type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="[Log Starts]%newline" />        
      <footer type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="[Log Ends]%newline" />        
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%username] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
     </appender>  

     <logger name="SRGApplicationDebugLog">
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
     </logger>
   </log4net>
```

Problem 1: I am getting header and footer **two times extra** whenever my application is started, but I need to avoid it.

> [Log Starts]
>      [Log Ends]
>      [Log Starts]
>      [Log Ends]
>       [Log Starts]
>      2012-11-08 12:25:03,376 [username] - Application started
>      [Log Ends]

Problem 2: I am not getting from where is the **two empty header footer pair** is coming.

1. I am creating logger like below:

```cs
_debugLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("SRGApplicationDebugLog");    
XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

1. To use Logger:

```cs
_debugLogger.DebugFormat(logMessage);
```

1. I have added this line explicitly in AssemblyInfo.cs for log4net

```cs
[assembly: XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

Question: Want to fix the problems in bold

Comment: Where are you configuring your logger? Could you share that piece of code?

Comment: updated the post for logger creation. I am doing it in app.config

Comment: Where in your application is the call to `GetLogger` and `XmlConfigurator.Configure()` is located? What kind of application is it? A web app or a console app etc? Sometimes it happens that these calls are placed in a a wrong location and they get called multiple times resulting in unwanted behavior.

Comment: GetLogger() and XmlConfigurator.Configure() are called in a static constructor of a 'LogHelper' class. _debugger is a static readonly Ilog variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need

```
 XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

if you have

```
[assembly: XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

Having both will result in the two headers and two footers.

As to why you have three sets, perhaps you are calling  `XmlConfigurator.Configure()` twice.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solved my problem. I removed XmlConfigurator.Configure() which i was using while creating a logger. Now [Log Starts] and [Log Ends] are just coming once.

Answer (score 0):

> Putting XmlConfigurator.Configure() at more than one places may result in having more >than one header and footer pair.
>
> XmlConfigurator.Configure() should be defined only at one place in the solution. Better >approach is to put it in AssemblyInfo.cs.